# "dynamically" use filenames in a .cmd/.bat

Tags: python, cmd

hoping this is a simple one but im not finding the answers i need by searching.

I am regularly running a python script that compares two zip files content from cmd, the syntax is:

python3 differ.py zip1.zip zip2.zip

im getting a little tired of typing out python3 the whole thing to run the files (i'm using tab but still). its being run from a folder where the two zips are always alphabetically the first files in the folder.

Effectively i would like to make a .cmd/.bat that i can just double click that picks up these two files, is that possible? the issue is that the zips are named via timestamp i.e. 2021-09-22_1200.zip
so the filenames are always changing, but one is always newer than the other if that helps in picking files.

it is not a python script i have written and i have no real experience with python itself, so would like to avoid modifying that unless its a real simple change!

cmd would be run from the folder containing the py script, the two zips, and one output folder (named starting Z to keep it out the way)

Answer (score 0):

> im getting a little tired of typing out python3 the whole thing to run the files (i'm using tab but still). its being run from a folder where the two zips are always alphabetically the first files in the folder.

Create a file (`differ.bat`) with the following code:

```
REM A differ.py wrapper
python3 differ.py %1 %2
```

Call the bat file like the below:

`differ zip1.zip zip2.zip`

Comment: yeah thats about as far as i got in simplifying it myself. still steps im hoping to skip if i can.
in an ideal world its one double click and thats it, no fire up cmd, then specify files.
ultimately all that bat would do is take out typing in "python3"

Comment: Do you want to create interactive script where you are prompted for the zip files? Please explain. How can the script know which files to use?

Comment: theyre the only two files in the directory alongside the script, hell they can be in their own directory if it helps. they automatically cycle every few hours.

Comment: so the python code can search for them ..